# How to implement HTML content inside my PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

A `PHP` page opened in my browser.

I have an `HTML` file with a jQuery AJAX call in it. When I post the data using AJAX, the HTML page disappear and the PHP file open instead.

I want to see the HTML result in the PHP page that I initially opened instead of opening a new HTML page.

What I have to do in my `phpfile`?

Thanks for help.

My HTML code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("#button").click(function(){
            $.post( "result.php",{ name : $('#text').val()  },
            function( data ) {
                $('#bigdiv').html(data);
                // alert(data);
            });
        }); //event handler
    }); //document.ready
</script>
```

And my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $name="";
    if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    }
    echo "name =  $name";
?>
```

Comment: The header explained the answer in a much better way and so is the question's body

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and assume that your button is tied to a form, so that it submits the form, and thus reloading the page, when you press it. Try adding this to your JavaScript:

```
$("#button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

//rest of your code...
```